# Why cast from MemberInfo to MethodInfo is allowed?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

Documentation for System.Reflection.[MemberInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.MemberInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the following example:

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers())  
{
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
    {
        foreach (ParameterInfo pi in ((MethodInfo)mi).GetParameters())
```

Notice the cast `(MethodInfo)mi)`. `MemberInfo` and `MethodInfo` don't have a common parent, so why cast is allowed ?

Comment: As the answers have already explained, `MethodInfo` derives from `MemberInfo`, indirectly. In addition, at runtime this doesn't throws an error because you're filtering those members that are methods, hence warranted to be `MethodInfo` when that code is ran.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MethodInfo` inherits from `MethodBase` which inherits from `MemberInfo`.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public abstract class MethodInfo : MethodBase, 
    _MethodInfo
```

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public abstract class MethodBase : MemberInfo, 
    _MethodBase
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. MemberInfo->MethodBase->MethodInfo. 
However, also notice that the cast is from parent to child, which is also wrong.

Comment: I don't see how polymorphism has to do with anything in this case. If I have `class b: a`, and I try to do `(b)new a()`, it will throw an exception. `(MethodInfo)mi)` is essentially the same thing. Up-casting from parent to child is not allowed.

Comment: @newprint Yes it is - simple example, suppose there are three types `A`, `B`, and `C`. `B` and `C` inherit from `A`. You can cast an `A` to one of it's children if it's actually the target type. For Example `A a = new B(); B b = (B) a;` is valid. In your comment, `(b)new a()` is in fact not valid because an instance of `a` is not an instance of `b`.

Comment: @newprint polymorphism lets you assign instance of `MethodInfo` to variable declared as `MemberInfo` and later on cast it back to `MethodInfo`. That's exactly what's happening in the code you quoted.

Comment: @jdphenix Oh, see where I was wrong. `mi` actually points to the type of `MethodInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

[`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is derived from [`MethodBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is derived from [`MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note that the `mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method` condition in the enclosing `if` guards from an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.